# How to get GID of one Google Sheet when given the url to another tab of that Sheet

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

By default, when you open a Google Sheet without any GID parameter in the URL, it will open to the first tab. I want to open to a specific tab which has a consistent tab name.

I have the url of a google sheet which I retrieved from our backend. I want to use that url to create a link to a specific tab in the spreadsheet, and then share that url to users. Through Java, how can I programatically retrieve the GID for that tab, or otherwise retrieve the URL for a specific tab, when I have the url to just the spreadsheet?

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.ServiceAccountKey;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class DriveUtils {

    // space out the requests at 'rate' per second. 0.50 is optimal
    private static double rate = 0.50;
    final static RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rate);

    public static Response run(ServiceAccountKey saResponse, ArrayList<Language> languages) {

        try {
            // Instantiate Sheets using the service account info
            Sheets sheets = getSheetsService(saResponse);
            ArrayList<Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get> getRequests = new ArrayList<Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get>();

            // Declare sheet tabs to check
            ArrayList<SheetValue> sheetValues = new ArrayList<SheetValue>();

            String range1 = "example1!1:1";
            String range2 = "example2!1:1";
            ArrayList<String> ranges = new ArrayList<String>();
            ranges.add(range1);
            ranges.add(range2);

            String header1 = "example";
            String header2 = "example2";
            ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
            headers.add(header1);
            headers.add(header2);

            for (int i = 0; i < languages.size(); i++) {
                String sheetUrl = DriveService.extractUrl(languages.get(i).getDoc_url());
                for (int j = 0; j < ranges.size(); j++) {
                    SheetValue sv = new SheetValue(
                            languages.get(i).getDoc_url(),
                            languages.get(i).getName(),
                            headers.get(j),
                            ranges.get(j),
                            sheetUrl
                    );
                    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get getRequest = sheets.spreadsheets().values()
                            .get(sv.getExtractedUrl(), sv.getRangeToCheck());
                    getRequests.add(getRequest);
                    sheetValues.add(sv);


                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < getRequests.size(); i++) {
                rateLimiter.acquire();
                sheetValues.set(i, DriveService.throttledFetch(getRequests.get(i), sheetValues.get(i)));
            }

            ArrayList<CheckObject> results = new ArrayList<CheckObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sheetValues.size(); i++) {
                results.add(sheetValues.get(i).getChecks());
            }
            return TallResponse.ok(results);

        } catch(IOException e) {
            String failure = "500 error: DriveUtils.run() failed";
            return TallResponse.internalServerError(failure,null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public static Sheets getSheetsService(ServiceAccountKey saResponse) throws IOException {
        HttpRequestInitializer httpri = SaService.credentialAuthorize();
        Sheets sheetService = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY, setTimeout(httpri,60000))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        return sheetService;
    }

    private static HttpRequestInitializer setTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer initializer, final int timeout) {
        return request -> {
            initializer.initialize(request);
            request.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        };
    }
}

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

public class DriveService {


    public static String extractUrl(String docId) {
        // Example:
        // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123Gfmom7BEvzIvyB6Ht3Sb5Q50rz8nytuEJJ7kzVs7y1I/edit#gid=4205522971
        // becomes:
        // 123Gfmom7BEvzIvyB6Ht3Sb5Q50rz8nytuEJJ7kzVs7y1I/
        int firstCutoff = docId.indexOf("/d/") + 3;
        String firstString = docId.substring(firstCutoff);
        int secondCutoff = firstString.indexOf("/edit");
        String finalString = firstString.substring(0, secondCutoff);
        return finalString;
    }

    public static SheetValue throttledFetch(Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get gr, SheetValue sv) throws IOException {

        try {
            //pull headers from sheet
            ValueRange response = gr.execute();
            } catch(IOException e) {
            return sv;
        }

        return sv;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i see your code how are you doing this?   You cant share a sheet with a user like this they would need to have permissions on the sheet for it to open in their google sheet web app.  That being said you should be able to add **#gid=tabId** on the end and it should open to that tab.

Comment: @DaImTo Added a code example. For this example I'm assuming that the user has permission to open the sheet. The problem with the #gid=tabId is that I don't have the tabId to the other tabs within the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.32.1'
}
```

The REST API documentation shows it - the API client's object has an identical structure:

[`Spreadsheets`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) ~> [`Sheets`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets) ~> [`SheetProperties`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties) ~> `sheetId` & `index`

> The ID of the sheet. Must be non-negative. This field cannot be changed once set.

You'd have to obtain the `sheetId` for the next one `index` value, where `hidden == false`.